# Not sure if my SQL JOIN is returning the correct set for my assignment

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I'm learning about JOINS and need help with the following question:

> Display a list of all books in the BOOKS table. If a book has been
>   ordered by a customer, also list the order number and state where the
>   customer resides.

This is what I can up with. Oracle 11g.

```
SELECT B.TITLE, O.ORDER#, C.STATE FROM BOOKS B
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERITEMS OI ON B.ISBN = OI.ISBN
   LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERS O ON O.ORDER# = OI.ORDER#
   LEFT OUTER JOIN CUSTOMERS C ON C.CUSTOMER# = O.CUSTOMER#;
```

This query is giving me 35 rows in the result. My BOOKS table only has 14 rows. My ORDERITEMS table has 32 rows. I'm assuming the 3 extra rows are books that have never been ordered? Does what I have even make sense. I'm figuring because the books table only has 14 rows, then that's all I should return? I don't think that's possible because the same book exists on multiple orders.

Comment: Your query and explanation seem correct.  What's your question?

Comment: Probably the 3 extra rows are books ordered by multiple customers.  `ORDER BY B.TITLE` to see them stacked together.  Your query looks correct to me.

Comment: Yup, I would expect to see a row for each order, and extra rows for books that have never been ordered. I think your query is correct. The question doesn't really address what to do with multiple orders for the same book..

Comment: Can you ask your teacher/professor/tutor to clarify?

Comment: @Blorgbeard I think that is my issue. I was thinking there's only 14 rows in the book table, but 35 rows are coming back. I wasn't sure if that's the way it should be or if it should only list each book once. Thanks. I'll check in with him.

Comment: what is this weird comma just before the 1st left join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may have started distinguishing `INNER JOIN` and `LEFT JOIN` based on that `LEFT JOIN` will not filter out any unmatched rows on the left side.  That, however, does not prevent the opposite from happening.

If you have multiple "orderitems" with the same ISBN (or, less likely, multiple orders with the same ORDER#, or multiple customers with the same CUSTOMER#), then *every* such match will duplicate the corresponding left-hand-side row, "books" in your case.

You can display the offending books like this:

```
SELECT B.TITLE, B.ISBN, COUNT(*) FROM BOOKS B
LEFT OUTER JOIN ORDERITEMS OI ON B.ISBN = OI.ISBN
GROUP BY B.ISBN, B.TITLE
HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```